# Comparing 2 large files (not in memory), where to begin

Tags: python

At the moment, I am doing a file comparison on 2 CSV files, checking for duplicate lines in each specific file, checking for data mismatches between the files, and checking for missing data rows in each file.

Currently, I am doing this in memory, built for speed because this will be processing thousands of files constantly. This comes at a price though, it can only process files it can completely store in memory.

I am looking to make a fall back if for some reason (although this should never happen) to be able to do the comparison if the files can't fit in memory.

What would be a good approach to do this?

Comment: What do you want to do with this comparison? If you just want to see if they differ, a hash or checksum would be sufficient. Otherwise, iterating through the files line by line is the memory-efficient way to proceed.

Comment: Please, read [how to ask useful questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @match   The reason I can't do line by line comparisons is that the data may be in a different order.  So for example, line 1 in the first file, might be the last line in the second file.  But I still want that to return as identical.  Since the containing data is the same.  I was thinking about perhaps hashing each line? Not sure if I would run into duplicate hashes though when we are talking about hundreds of millions of hashes.  That's my current best solution, looking for a possible better one because finding the line each hash belongs to if we find a difference would take a long time

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas. Can't beat it for data analysis in python.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Comes complete with a

```
read_csv(filepath, skiprows=100000, nrows=9999999)
```

method that loads the specified rows.

It's built on numpy, the majority of which's methods are implement in C, making them incredibly fast.